# Why is my code not working whenever I try do an F-string

Tags: python

```
age = 17
age_last_year = age - 1
print(f"last year it was {age_last_year} 16.")
```

I know its extremely basic and it's my first-day coding but I'm so lost
thanks
xd

Comment: You miss `"` in the end

Comment: `print(f"last year it was {age_last_year}.")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot **"** at the end of **print** statement.

```
age = 17
age_last_year = age - 1
print(f"last year it was {age_last_year}.")
```

Output

```
>>> last year it was 16.
```

**Or you can do using format**

```
age = 17
age_last_year = age - 1
print("last year it was {}.".format(age_last_year))
```

Output

```
>>> last year it was 16.
```